# My Greasemonkey script works when typed in the console, but not when I try to use it in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I am having trouble running a simple GreaseMonkey script I made to clean up the search results on DuckDuckGo.com. The code below simply removes the "Images" and "Videos" buttons from the results.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Relevance
// @include     http://duckduckgo.com/*
// @include     https://duckduckgo.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

function Relevant(){
    var killIt=["zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--images  ", "zcm__link  js-zci-link  js-zci-link--videos  "];
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) 
        {
            for (j=0;j<killIt.length; j++) 
                {
                    if (el[i].className==killIt[j]) 
                        {
                            el[i].parentNode.removeChild(el[i]);
                        }
                }
        }
};


$(window).load (Relevant());
```

The code works when typed in the console, but it doesn't work as a Greasemonkey script. I tried to adapt the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7539088/works-as-javascript-but-doesnt-work-as-a-greasemonkey-script) (i.e., use `$(window).load (Relevant());`), but I'm still having trouble. This is my first attempt at making my own user script, so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `$(window).load (Relevant());` invokes `Relevant` immediately....not as callback. That said `$(window).load()` is deprecated. Also possible the elements don't exist immediately if they are loaded by script. Also do some research into what `safeWindow` is in userScript

Comment: you aren't requiring jQuery, but you are using it?

Comment: Any error info in console?

Comment: @charlietfl: I'm afraid I didn't realize that was depcrecated. Is there a more up-to-date approach you would recommend to invoke it as callback? Also, I only found [unsafeWindow](https://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow). Is that what you meant? Based on the warnings on that page, I'm wondering if I should use something else.

Comment: @lossleader: Thank you for pointing that out. I have now required jQuery. I assumed that since it worked in the console, it should work from the script, but I have changed it.

Comment: @blackmiaool: Thank you for the helpful suggestion. As far as I can tell, the warnings on the page are due to the way the page itself is written, and not due to my script (they show up when my script is disabled). The only one that seems significant is [unreachable code after return statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default). I don't have any `return` statements in my code, so I'm fairly certain this is due to the way the page itself is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @charlietfl said, the `$(window).load (Relevant());` invokes Relevant immediately, it should be changed to `$(Relevant)`.

If it works, try this: https://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at

If this doesn't work, try to use `setTimeout(Relevant,3000)`;

It's very usual that the code works in console doesn't work in greasemonkey, becase the doms may not be rendered when the greasemonkey script runs.

Comment: Thank you so much! As you mentioned, `$(window).load (Relevant());` was invoking the function too soon. Changing to `$(Relevant)` was all it took! 

Another thing I did change is that I used the most recent [jQuery version](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery). I'm not sure if that had an effect, but thought I should mention that as well.